# Does somebody know how to remove the need of Update/Delete/edit actions from Gift-Message?

Tags: magento2

Unfortunately, to enter a gift-message customers have to click on update button to store the message. If he is not doing this, the message is not stored after the checkout is processed.

This is not good because each unneccessary click in the checkout is a bad click and I would like to have the gift-message without the need of these buttons.

Some extensions for an order comment doing it without the need of pressing a button for saving the comment.

Does somebody know how to do this or does somebody know an extension which is doing it?

Regards,
Chequille

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this on the cart page then try using this

https://www.rltsquare.com/blog/ajax-shopping-cart-update-magento-2-extension/

https://github.com/MaxMage/ajax-shopping-cart-page

Might help you

Comment: No, this does not help, because I am talking about the checkout.page. The Gift message is only saved when clicking on the update button.

Comment: ok, I thought that if ajax will work then it will be done within the process. Actually, it would be helpful if we get to see what exactly you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,, Guys,
this is a screenshot from my checkout page with the gift-message. This gift message is the standard Magento module-gift-message.

[image]

This gift message is only applied to the order if the user clicks on the "Speichern" button. In english the button is named "Update".
My wish is, that the entered message is stored without the need to click on "Speichern". It should be saved when the user is finally placing the order.

If the "Speichern" Button is clicked, the whole page is re-loaded.